# Serverless Framework: Is there a way to put index.js file in root of zipped package using serverless?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am having trouble deploying outputted zip file when running serverless package, as the `index.js` file is not located in root.

For context, the lambda function to be deployed was developed in a separate repo (different package.json, diff git repo) from the main project (a next js site). And I deploy it just by zipping the folder into a zip file and uploading that. When doing this, the index.js file is in the root of the zipped directory, so there's no problem doing that.

Now, I've moved the lambda function folder (also removed its package.json and node_modules, since I don't want a subrepo) inside the main project. So my folder structure looks like this:

```
main-project-directory
- node_modules
- serverless
  - function-folder
    - other_files/
    - index.js
- serverless.yml
```

I'm using serverless to package it so it can use the main project's packages. It works when I'm testing using serverless-offline, however, the issue is when I run `serverless package` it outputs a zip file with no index.js in the root directory. Instead, the zip file's folder structure looks like this:

```
zip-file
  - node_modules
  - serverless
    - function-folder
      - other_files/
      - index.js
```

Is there a way to configure it so when I run `serverless package` the folder structure of the zipped file looks like this:

```
zip-file
  - node_modules
  - other_files/
  - index.js
```

this is my serverless.yml:

```
service: 'service'

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - '!./**'
    - 'serverless/function_folder/**'
    - 'node_modules/dependency1/**'
    - 'node_modules/dependency2/**'
    - 'node_modules/dependency3/**'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x

functions:
  function_folder:
    handler: ./serverless/function_folder/index.handler
```

Or if there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks!